# Search user by tag command in discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I am trying to do a command that searches for users that have the same tag as the author, I am trying to list them nicely but I am running through a `TypeError`.

My code is:

```
@bot.command()
async def tag(ctx, tag):
    tag1 = tag[1:]
    counter = 0
    guild = ctx.guild
    for member in guild.members:
        if tag == member.discriminator or tag1 == member.discriminator:
            found = "\n".join([member.name for member in guild.members if tag1 == member.discriminator or tag == member.discriminator])
            found2 = "\n".join([member.id for member in guild.members if tag1 == member.discriminator or tag == member.discriminator])
            counter += 1
            await ctx.send(f"{found} - {found2}")
            return
```

The error is: `Command raised an exception: TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, int found`

I know the part that is causing the error, but I don't know how to fix it, the part that causes this error is: `found2 = "\n".join([member.id for member in guild.members if tag1 == member.discriminator or tag == member.discriminator])`

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theres more than 1 problem with your code, and even if you get it to run you won't get the result you said you wanted.

---

#### Function arguments

Discord passes the following arguments to a command function:

```
async def command(Context, *Message)
```

The first argument is always the Discord context, the second (and following) arguments are every word that was written after the command:

If you would write `.command This is a Test`, Discord would pass the arguments as following:

```
Context, This, is, a, Test
```

Adding a * before an argument in your definition means this argument contains all arguments remaining. So, in this example, the *Message would collect `(This, is, a, Test)`

With that said, your `tag` argument wouldnt do anything else than catching the first word that was written after the command call.

How to get the tag of the author:

```
authorTag = ctx.author.discriminator
```

---

#### Return statement

In your Code, as soon as you match 1 person, you call the return statement. This would stop the function to run, and means you only match the first person who has the same tag, everyone else after would not be checked.

---

#### Code length

Try to write your code that no line exceeds 80-100 letters.
This makes it way more readable for you and for others. You shouldn't be forced to scroll sidewards. Of course, if you think there is no other way, go for it, but try to avoid it.

---

#### Your Code doesn't do what you want it to do

Go carefully through your code:

- You make a for loop that checks every member.
- Continue if that member has the same tag as the author.
- Now, make a list which contains every member name of the guild
- and make a list which contains every member id of the guild
- merge the two lists and send them, now stop the code

I rewrote the code to actually match what you wanted to do (at least I hope so):

```
@client.command()
async def tag(ctx):

    authorTag = ctx.author.discriminator
    guild = ctx.guild

    sameTag = []

    for member in guild.members:
        if authorTag == member.discriminator and member != ctx.author:
            sameTag.append(f"{member.name} - {str(member.discriminator)}")
    
    if len(sameTag) == 0:
        sameTag.append("No matches found") 
    
    await ctx.send("\n".join(sameTag))
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `member.id` to a `str`:

```py
found2 = "\n".join([str(member.id) for member in guild.members if tag1 == member.discriminator or tag == member.discriminator])
```